# What exactly constitutes a newline at the end of a file?

Tags: parsing, text, language-agnostic, newline

I personally try to place a newline at the end of all of my source files, especially in the C++ world where the compiler generates a warning for this condition. To ensure that I've done this, I typically just look for a blank line at the end of each file I edit.

That said, a number of different editors seem to treat the final newline character differently (at least on Windows). Consider this example file (I've chosen to show line numbers):

```
1: One
2: Two
3: Three
4:
```

The hex output of this file is as follows:

```
4F6E650D 0A54776F 0D0A5468 7265650D 0A
```

Note that the last character pair in this file is a `0D0A` (`\r\n`). When I open this file in various editors or viewers, they all do something different:

#### Editors that show line 4:

- Sublime Text 3
- Visual Studio
- Notepad

#### Editors that do not show line 4:

- SlickEdit
- vim
- WinMerge file viewer
- GitLab online viewer

So, what exactly constitutes a "newline at end of file?" Are the differences in these (and other) applications merely a result of the parsing engines? Is there a "correct" answer to whether line 4 should be shown or not? It seems to me that showing line 4 is the correct option.

Answer (score 0):

This actually has very little to do with being the end of the file, it's just that's the effect you're seeing.

You should ask yourself first where the *initial* newline is. Is it at the end of the first line, *between* the first and second, or *before* the second?

Sorry to go all Zen on you but that's basically what you're asking. I've always considered a newline "character" to be part of the line which it follows (probably based on my C history, with `fgets` and such).

But, I can at least conceive the viewpoint that it's *between* the lines, as some of your editors seem to think. That would mean they'd treat line 4 as an empty line without a newline on the end, which is not a view I subscribe to - my view is, if you have an empty room with no walls, floor or ceiling, you can't really call it a room.

I *can't* envisage ever considering the newline as being at the start of the next line.